# How to sort list of object by time in java

Tags: java, sorting, object

What is the best way(FAST), how to sort list of my object by time (hour:minute:second);

i have list of object:

```
ArrayList<myObject> test = new ArrayList<>();
```

i have class:

```
public class myObject{

private final myTime actualTime;
private final String name;

public myObject(int hour, int minute, int second, String name){
     this.actualTime = new myTime(hour, minute, second);
     this.name = name;
}

private class myTime{
     private final hour, minute, second;
     public myTime(int hour, int minute, int second){
          this.hour=hour;
          this.minute = minute;
          this.second =second;
     }
}

}
```

Create test object:

```
test.add(new myObject(1, 0, 0, "Name1")); //1 hour, 0 minute, 0second...
test.add(new myObject(9, 0, 0, "Name2"));
test.add(new myObject(2, 0, 0, "Name3"));

//now i want sort, but i dont know how?
//i want print: Name2, Name3, Name1
```

I hope, you understand me, thank you for your advice.

EDIT1:

```
   @Override
        public int compareTo(Object t) {
            hourTmp = ((myTime) t).getHour();
            if (this.getHour() > hourTmp) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: why not using one of java's `Date, DateTime, Calendar` classes and sort by it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [`Collections.sort(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) method which will perform a merge sort for you. But before you can use it you should make your custom class implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

When implementing `Comparable`, you will need to implement the `compareTo(myClass o)` method and perform the comparison inside that method on whatever member you desire.

Comment: Thank you, but how to effective implement `Comparable` for 3 values(hour, minute, time) ?

Comment: @niawaemi the `Comparable` interface has a single method which should return 0 if the objects are equal, -1 if the object is "less than" and 1 if the object is "greater than". How you define 'equal', 'less', and 'greater' depends upon your object. Try defining the function to work on only hours first, then add in minutes and finally seconds.

Comment: Its not working, look at my post to EDIT1 chaper. If i call: `Arrays.sort(listOfItems.toArray(new myObject[listOfItems.size()]));` program can go to my override method, but not sort my list.

Comment: @niawaemi: I've updated my answer since. Try this: `Collections.sort(test);`, this way, the transformation from list to array is done behind the scenes for you. Update your full code, including the getters, to better debug your problem.

Comment: @niawaemi: In your `compareTo` method, you probably want `if (this.actualTime.getHour() > hourTmp)` rathen than `if (this.getHour() > hourTmp)`, as `getHour()` is a getter of the `myTime` class. Also the argument of the `compareTo` method needs to be casted to the type that implements `Comparable` (myObject in your case).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) method with a provided `Comparator`, or make your object implement `Comparable`.

Here is how you could create a `Comparator` in java 8 (after adding getters for time values):

```
Comparator.comparingInt(myTime::getHour)
              .thenComparingInt(myTime::getMinute)
              .thenComparingInt(myTime::getSecond);
```